# establecer ancho y margenes de cardview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

tengo una aplicacion con un recyclerview que contiene varios cardviews. Y el caso es que no se como establecer el ancho del cardview para que ocupe todo el ancho de la pantalla. Tampoco se como hacer para que cada cardview este separado del anterior y del siguiente. He añadido margenes a todos los elementos pero los cardview se me muestran juntos. Esta es una captura de como se ve el layout: [captura de pantalla](https://postimg.cc/RqG0VCdX)

y este es el codigo de los dos layouts. Primero el del mainactivity que contiene el recyclerview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/escanearCodigo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Escanear codigo"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

y este el de cada item del recyclerview (el que contiene los carviews):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#81C784"
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
    app:cardElevation="3dp"
    app:contentPadding="4dp"
    >
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/idCodigo"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/idNombre"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo tener la siguiente estructura:

```
**LinearLayout** -> match-parent, wrap-content, vertical, center horizontal, weightSum= "2"
**LinearLayou** -> match-parent, wrap-content, center horizontal, 
**CardView** -> layout_margin "8dp" layout_marginEnd "16dp"
```